# Shortcode won't render in correct place

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I'm trying to output my shortcode content before the main content body, I simply cannot get it to work and nor can I find the answer.

If I use a simple string or number, it outputs in the correct place but when I try to output the table html it renders below the content.

EDIT: I've just checked the source code - the code renders in the correct order but is shown differently. I'm really confused.

My code is as follows:

```
/* SHORTCODES */


        //inject code on initialization
        add_action('init', 'ebs_register_shortcodes');

        //register shortcodes
        function ebs_register_shortcodes() {
        add_shortcode('offer_table', 'ebs_table_shortcode');
        }

        function ebs_table_shortcode() {

        $page_offers = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'offers_on_page', true);
        $rank = 1;

        //Table Content
        $table = '<table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th>Brands</th>
        <th>User Rating</th>
        <th>Signup Bonus</th>
        <th>Key Features</th>
        <th>Play Now</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>';

        foreach ($page_offers as $index => $page_id) {

        $table .= '<td>'.$rank.'</td>';
        $table .= '<td>'.get_field('ebs_brand_logo', $page_id).'</td>';

        if ( get_field('ebs_launch_date' !== '') ) { 
        $table .= '<td>'.get_field('ebs_launch_date', $page_id).'</td>';
        }

        $table .= '<td>'.get_field('ebs_rating', $page_id).'</td>';
        //echo '<td>'.get_field('ebs_review_link', $page_id).'</td>';
        $table .= '<td>'.get_field('ebs_signup_bonus', $page_id).'</td>';
        $table .= '<td>'.get_field('ebs_key_features', $page_id).'</td>';
        $table .= '<td>'.get_field('ebs_clean_link', $page_id).'</td>';
        //$table .= '<td>'.get_field('ebs_brand_name', $page_id).'</td>';

        $table .= '</tr>';
        $rank++;

        }

        $table .= '</tbody><br>';

        //return the table
        return $table;

        }
```

Thankyou in advance for any help!

Comment: you should start the `<tr>` inside the foreach at the start, now you are only doing it once...

Comment: Fixed, thanks for that catch! Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

The issue was a missing  tag.